# Observe inside Observe returns wrong value

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm observing two values in my Fragment, one is an ID set from another Fragment, and another is an object returned from my database based on that ID.

I'm trying to do the following in my onViewCreated

```
corpoViewModel.getIdTestata().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { id ->
    corpoViewModel.getTestataById(id.toInt()).observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { testata ->
        txtData.setText(testata.data)
        txtTipo.setText(testata.tipo)
        txtNumDoc.setText(testata.id.toString())
    })
})
```

So firstly i get the id and then i observe for the object by passing in that id.

The issue is that after i change X times the value ID it breaks and show wrong values like:

ID 1, i show 1
new ID 2, i show 2
new ID 3, i show 2

in my debug the observe enter three times in it and as last value set 2 in id...

Comment: are you removing the observers when you finish with this logic ?

Comment: @LenaBru i don't but i solved by using switchMap